# Single button to edit user and submit image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to edit a user details and in the same time Upload a photo with the same button, but `HttpPostedFileBase` is always null when I am trying to save the file.

**Image Model**

```
public class Image
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public int ImageSize { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public int Counter { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select file")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual Job Jobs { get; set; }
}
```

**ParentViewModel**

```
public class ImgAndUser
{
    public EditUserViewModel EditUser { get; set; }
    public Image EditImage { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(ImgAndUser IU, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null && IU.EditImage.File.ContentLength > (2 * 1024 * 1024))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Custom Error", "File must be less than 2 MB or doesn't exist");
            return View();
        }
        else if(!(IU.EditImage.File.ContentType == "image/jpeg" || IU.EditImage.File.ContentType == "image/gif" || IU.EditImage.File.ContentType == "image/jpg"))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "Only jpeg and gif formats");
            return View();
        }

        else
        {
            string fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            string path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/FilesDB/Images");
            file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/FilesDB/Images"), fileName));

            IU.EditImage.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
            IU.EditImage.FileName = IU.EditImage.File.FileName;
            IU.EditImage.ImageSize = IU.EditImage.File.ContentLength;

            byte[] data = new byte[IU.EditImage.File.ContentLength];
            IU.EditImage.File.InputStream.Read(data, 0, IU.EditImage.File.ContentLength);

            IU.EditImage.ImageData = data;
            IU.EditImage.UserID = LoggedUserId;
            IU.EditImage.FilePath = path;
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {                     
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(IU.EditUser.Id);

            if (user == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "User not found");
            }

            else
            {
                user.Email = IU.EditUser.Email;
                user.Name = IU.EditUser.Name;
                user.Surname = IU.EditUser.Surname;
                user.City = IU.EditUser.City;
                user.ZIP = IU.EditUser.ZIP;
                user.Street = IU.EditUser.Street;
                user.Nr = IU.EditUser.Nr;
                user.CompName = IU.EditUser.CompName;
                user.CUI = IU.EditUser.CUI;
                user.DescCompany = IU.EditUser.DescCompany;

                try
                {
                    //collect all images except final one
                    var existImgRows = context.Images.Where(x => x.UserID == LoggedUserId).OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).Skip(0).Select(x => x);

                    if (existImgRows != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in existImgRows)
                        {
                            context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
                        }
                    }
                    context.Entry(IU.EditImage).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Jobs", new { controller = "JobsController", action = "Details", id = Session["DetailsURL"] });
                }

                catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
                {
                    foreach (var validationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Property: {0} throws Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something failed");
        return View();
    }
```

In the `else { }` statement `string fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);` the parameter `file` is `null`, but if statements are passed with data of the file I select in the browser.

**Edit View:**

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "ImgAndUser", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) 
{ 
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.EditUser.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.EditUser.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.EditUser.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.EditUser.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>   
.
.
         Losts of stuff similar with above.
.
.
    </div>  

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.EditImage.ID);
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Select File : </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Image => Model.EditImage.File, new { type = "file" })
                @Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError")
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Comment: Its unclear what your trying to achieve with this (you have 2 separate forms so they will post to 2 seperate actions (`HttpPostedFileBase file` will always be `null` because its not part of the 'Edit' form

Comment: If you want to edit the details and upload an image, include the file input in the 'Edit' view so all data is submitted, and then save the file and the data in the `Edit()` method.

Comment: Editing user details and uploading image simultaneously with a button click requires a parent viewmodel that holds 2 separate models, or a common model that bound to view and partial view including a property that declared as `HttpPostedFileBase`. If you can't execute both operations at the same time by design, consider which one processed first then redirect to second action.

Comment: Thanks for messages, I didn't had time to work at project in last 2 weeks, today I made a parent view model for Image model and EditUserViewModel but the HttpPostedFileBase is always null. I will edit the previous question shortly.